# How to only plot data on the hour from a 6 hour dataset cube (iris)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, iris-dataset, python-iris

So far my code to plot a a graph is like so:

```
iplt.plot(pressure_no1, color='black')
plt.xlabel('Time / hour of day')
plt.ylabel('Atmospheric pressure / kPa')
iplt.show()
```

it is a 6 hour cube (although is 2dimensional) data set, with 420 data points. I need just the data points hr=0, hr=1 hr=2, hr=3, hr=4, hr=5 to be plotted and none in between the hour.

could something like the following work?

```
pressure_no1_hrs = pressure_no1.coord('hour'==int).points
plt.plot(pressure_no1_hrs)
```

[Image of graph with all data points and start of the time coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8dav.png)
[Image of last lot of time coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkirH.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. How does `pressure_no1` look like? You might want to work with the modulo operator to filter out the timepoints that correspond to the full hour.

Comment: maybe first check if works `pressure_no1.coord('hour'==int).points` before you ask for this. It will be faster if you first test some ideas before you ask.

Comment: @Molitoris thanks for the suggetsion. I am a bit of a noob so im not sure what that means, how might i do that? pressure_no1 has a time constraint to a 6 hour period, and is made up of atmospheric pressure and time coordinates

Comment: @furas this didnt work, but i wondered if i might be on a good track. I dont know much about python/iris coding

Comment: Can you append a sample of your dataset?

Comment: I don't know `python/iris` and I only suggest standard methods to work with problems - first run code to test your idea(s), next search information in documentation, next use Google to get other resources with information - ie. some tutorials, finally ask on Stackoverflow. And if you tested code then describe it in question and add full error message (in question, not in comment).

Comment: @Molitoris I have added the current data graph and the time coordinates to give an idea of what theyre like. I hope this is what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an Iris-specific solution, you could use a [PartialDateTime](https://scitools-iris.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/api/iris/time.html?highlight=PartialDateTime#iris.time.PartialDateTime):

```
import iris
import iris.quickplot as qplt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

measures = np.random.normal(size=(360, ))
timepoints = np.arange(start=0, stop=360)

cube = iris.cube.Cube(measures, long_name='atmospheric_pressure', units='kPa')
time_coord = iris.coords.DimCoord(
    timepoints, units='minutes since 2020-07-01 00:00', standard_name='time')
cube.add_dim_coord(time_coord, 0)

subcube = cube.extract(iris.Constraint(time=iris.time.PartialDateTime(minute=0)))

qplt.plot(cube, label='All data')
qplt.plot(subcube, label='Hourly data')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping! and the graph looks great :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


measures = np.random.normal(size=(360, ))
timepoints = np.arange(start=0, stop=360)


df = pd.DataFrame({'measure': measures, 'timepoint': timepoints})

is_hour = df.loc[:, 'timepoint'] % 60 == 0  # <- Only select full hour

plt.plot(df.loc[is_hour, 'measure'])
plt.xlabel("Time [min]")
plt.ylabel("Atmospheric pressure / kPa")
plt.show()
```